# Why can't this reference be resolved?

Tags: .net, reference

I updated my Sharp-Architecture libraries to the newest version and all of a sudden I'm getting unable to resolve errors - specifically with NHibernate Validators.

I am not quite sure why though, here is what my test assembly looks like in reflector:

[image]

But the NHibernate.Validator library with the exact same version number/public key is in the same directory!

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: It says on the close menu how many votes have been applied to each closure reason. It seems to be incorrect though - anything including the word "reflector" shouldn't go on superuser :)

Comment: @Rex - what? I don't get the second part of your sentence at all.

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a version of the assembly in the GAC or possibly on the $Path variable?

Comment: That's an idea, there sure might be, shouldn't it look in the local directory first though?  How can I tell it to do so?

Comment: Not in the GAC, and none of the stuff on $PATH seems like it would contain NHibernate.Validator

Comment: Take a look at the fusion (.NET binder) logs. This may give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks that did help me figure it out.  I had to open my csproj file in a text editor but then I could see there that the relative path for the library was the wrong directory and for the wrong version.  Changing it by hand helped.